# Post a php variable

Tags: php, html, post

Hello I'Ve tried to post my username into my insert page but they say  Undefined index: usrUserName .

in my autocomplete.php I tried to see what wrong. if i make that :

```
    <input type="text" name="data1" value="<?php echo $usrUserName; ?>" />

I see my username so I know i receive it from my connection. When I post it

    <form action = 'insert.php' method="post"  >
                    <input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly" name="total" />

    <input type="submit"  value="Terminé" id="end" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="data1" value="<?php echo $usrUserName; ?>" />


    </form>
```

I got the error . 
this is my insert.php page

```
//récupération des variable 
$date = $_POST['data'] ;
$usrUserName =  $_POST['usrUserName'] ;
echo($usrUserName);

if (isSet($_POST['descprojsam']))
    {
    $usrUserName =  $_POST['usrUserName'] ;
    echo($usrUserName);
        $descprojsam = $_POST['descprojsam'] ;
    }
    echo($date);
```

Comment: You don't have a form element named `usrUserName` you may have it confused with `name="data1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You collect post variables by their name attribute. But in your input its data1. Change it to usrUserName

```
 <input type="text" name="usrUserName" value="<?php echo $usrUserName; ?>" />
```

**OR**

change the post attribute itslef in the php

```
$usrUserName = $_POST['data1'];
```

Comment: @Thephpdoge please check the answer if its able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="data1" value="<?php echo $usrUserName; ?>" />
```

In the above line, it is evident that Input with the name "`data1`" contains value of `$usrUserName`.

So, in your `insert.php`, change `$_POST['usrUserName']`  to `$_POST['data1'];`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you POSTed the data with different names. Your $usrUserName is posted as "data1".

Try this:

```
$usrUserName = $_POST['data1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : ""  ;
$usrUserName =  isset($_POST['data1']) ? $_POST['data1'] : "" ;
echo($usrUserName);

if (isset($_POST['descprojsam']))
{
echo "$usrUserName";
    $descprojsam = isset($_POST['descprojsam']) ?  $_POST['descprojsam'] : "";
}
echo($date);
```

Undefined Index is a type error warning in php variable must setear:

```
 $usrUserName =  isset($_POST['data1']) ? $_POST['data1'] : "" ;
```